# converting degrees minutes and tenths of seconds to decimal

Tags: php, math, degrees

Being hampered by some code converting degrees minutes and (tenths/decimal) seconds to decimal format:

```
function convertDMSToDecimal($latlng) {
$valid = false;
$decimal_degrees = 0;
$degrees = 0; $minutes = 0; $seconds = 0; $direction = 1;
// Determine if there are extra periods in the input string
$num_periods = substr_count($latlng, '.');
if ($num_periods > 1) {
    $temp = preg_replace('/\./', ' ', $latlng, $num_periods - 1); // replace all but last period with delimiter
    $temp = trim(preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]/','',$temp)); // when counting chunks we only want numbers
    $chunk_count = count(explode(" ",$temp));
    if ($chunk_count > 2) {
        $latlng = preg_replace('/\./', ' ', $latlng, $num_periods - 1); // remove last period
    } else {
        $latlng = str_replace("."," ",$latlng); // remove all periods, not enough chunks left by keeping last one
    }
}

// Remove unneeded characters
$latlng = trim($latlng);
$latlng = str_replace("º"," ",$latlng);
$latlng = str_replace("°"," ",$latlng);
$latlng = str_replace("'"," ",$latlng);
$latlng = str_replace("\""," ",$latlng);
$latlng = str_replace("  "," ",$latlng);
$latlng = substr($latlng,0,1) . str_replace('-', ' ', substr($latlng,1)); // remove all but first dash
if ($latlng != "") {
    // DMS with the direction at the start of the string
    if (preg_match("/^([nsewNSEW]?)\s*(\d{1,3})\s+(\d{1,3})\s+(\d+\.?\d*)$/",$latlng,$matches)) {
        $valid = true;
        $degrees = intval($matches[2]);
        $minutes = intval($matches[3]);
        $seconds = floatval($matches[4]);
        if (strtoupper($matches[1]) == "S" || strtoupper($matches[1]) == "W")
            $direction = -1;
    }
    // DMS with the direction at the end of the string
    elseif (preg_match("/^(-?\d{1,3})\s+(\d{1,3})\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([nsewNSEW]?)$/",$latlng,$matches)) {
        $valid = true;
        $degrees = intval($matches[1]);
        $minutes = intval($matches[2]);
        $seconds = floatval($matches[3]);
        if (strtoupper($matches[4]) == "S" || strtoupper($matches[4]) == "W" || $degrees < 0) {
            $direction = -1;
            $degrees = abs($degrees);
        }
    }
    if ($valid) {
        // A match was found, do the calculation
        $decimal_degrees = ($degrees + ($minutes / 60) + ($seconds / 3600)) * $direction;


    } else {
        // Decimal degrees with a direction at the start of the string
        if (preg_match("/^([nsewNSEW]?)\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/",$latlng,$matches)) {
            $valid = true;
            if (strtoupper($matches[1]) == "S" || strtoupper($matches[1]) == "W")
                $direction = -1;
            $decimal_degrees = $matches[2] * $direction;
        }
        // Decimal degrees with a direction at the end of the string
        elseif (preg_match("/^(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([nsewNSEW]?)$/",$latlng,$matches)) {
            $valid = true;
            if (strtoupper($matches[2]) == "S" || strtoupper($matches[2]) == "W" || $degrees < 0) {
                $direction = -1;
                $degrees = abs($degrees);
            }
            $decimal_degrees = $matches[1] * $direction;
        }
    }
}
if ($valid) {
    return $decimal_degrees;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

My issue is both my math skills and my abilty to amend the code to suit my use case.

After some investigation we are entering degrees, minutes, seconds but with the seconds in tengths so 100 in 1 minute rather than in 60 in 1 minute of latitude.

I've tried so many variations it's making my head spin!

I think I need to change the seconds back from a decimal format to a seconds format and then use that to change the whole into a decimal.

I'm pretty sure this is what I need to amend:

```
$decimal_degrees = ($degrees + ($minutes / 60) + ($seconds / 3600)) * $direction;
```

As the seconds are in decimal formats, I think / 3600 is probably wrong.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you have an example of the input string to the function?

Comment: convertDMSToDecimal($lat)

Comment: Sorry inadvertant enter key! I use the function like this...
convertDMSToDecimal($lat) with $lat being in this case 50.21.630N.
What I should get returned is 50.360503 however the seconds are decimal seconds not seconds in the true sense of 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted!

I had to merge the minutes and seconds together and get the math right to change it to decimal. Here is the completed code for taking degrees, minutes, decimal seconds from a GPS unit or navigation chart and outputting the entry as a decimal.

They key part was this section...

```
     //do the calculation
     $minsSecsCombined = $minutes.'.'.$seconds; //Combine the minutes and seconds together
     $math = (($minsSecsCombined / 3600) * 60) * 10000; //Math

     $degrees = $degrees.'.'.$math; //Combine the degrees and result together
     $degrees = number_format((float)$degrees, 6, '.', ''); //Ensure the result is classed as a number

     $decimal_degrees = $degrees * $direction; //Put them all together
```

And this is the completed code all together...

```
function convertDMSToDecimal($latlng) {
 $valid = false;
 $decimal_degrees = 0;
 $degrees = 0; $minutes = 0; $seconds = 0; $direction = 1;
 // Determine if there are extra periods in the input string
 $num_periods = substr_count($latlng, '.');
 if ($num_periods > 1) {
     $temp = preg_replace('/\./', ' ', $latlng, $num_periods - 1); // replace all but last period with delimiter
     $temp = trim(preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]/','',$temp)); // when counting chunks we only want numbers
     $chunk_count = count(explode(" ",$temp));
     if ($chunk_count > 2) {
         $latlng = preg_replace('/\./', ' ', $latlng, $num_periods - 1); // remove last period
     } else {
         $latlng = str_replace("."," ",$latlng); // remove all periods, not enough chunks left by keeping last one
     }
 }

 // Remove unneeded characters
 $latlng = trim($latlng);
 $latlng = str_replace("º"," ",$latlng);
 $latlng = str_replace("°"," ",$latlng);
 $latlng = str_replace("'"," ",$latlng);
 $latlng = str_replace("\""," ",$latlng);
 $latlng = str_replace("  "," ",$latlng);
 $latlng = substr($latlng,0,1) . str_replace('-', ' ', substr($latlng,1)); // remove all but first dash
 if ($latlng != "") {
    // DMS with the direction at the start of the string
     if (preg_match("/^([nsewNSEW]?)\s*(\d{1,3})\s+(\d{1,3})\s+(\d+\.?\d*)$/",$latlng,$matches)) {
         $valid = true;
         $degrees = $matches[2];
         $minutes = $matches[3];
         $seconds = $matches[4];
         if (strtoupper($matches[1]) == "S" || strtoupper($matches[1]) == "W")
             $direction = -1;
     }
     // DMS with the direction at the end of the string
     elseif (preg_match("/^(-?\d{1,3})\s+(\d{1,3})\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([nsewNSEW]?)$/",$latlng,$matches)) {
         $valid = true;
         $degrees = $matches[1];
         $minutes = $matches[2];
         $seconds = $matches[3];
         if (strtoupper($matches[4]) == "S" || strtoupper($matches[4]) == "W" || $degrees < 0) {
             $direction = -1;
             $degrees = abs($degrees);
         }
     }
     if ($valid) {
         // A match was found, do the calculation
         $minsSecsCombined = $minutes.'.'.$seconds; //Combine the minutes and seconds together

 //hack to sort missing 0 - If a latitude or longitude starts with a 0 the calculation strips it out making it up to 9miles off location once calculated. This code cheats by re-adding the 0
 if (substr($minutes, 0, 1 ) === "0") {
   $math = '0'.$math;
 }
         $math = (($minsSecsCombined / 3600) * 60) * 10000; //Math

         $degrees = $degrees.'.'.$math; //Combine the degrees and result together
         $degrees = number_format((float)$degrees, 6, '.', ''); //Ensure the result is classed as a number

         $decimal_degrees = $degrees * $direction; //Put them all together


     } else {
         // Decimal degrees with a direction at the start of the string
         if (preg_match("/^([nsewNSEW]?)\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/",$latlng,$matches)) {
             $valid = true;
             if (strtoupper($matches[1]) == "S" || strtoupper($matches[1]) == "W")
                 $direction = -1;
             $decimal_degrees = $matches[2] * $direction;
         }
         // Decimal degrees with a direction at the end of the string
         elseif (preg_match("/^(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([nsewNSEW]?)$/",$latlng,$matches)) {
             $valid = true;
             if (strtoupper($matches[2]) == "S" || strtoupper($matches[2]) == "W" || $degrees < 0) {
                 $direction = -1;
                 $degrees = abs($degrees);
             }
             $decimal_degrees = $matches[1] * $direction;
         }
     }
 }
 if ($valid) {
     return $decimal_degrees;
 } else {
     return false;
 }
 }
```